# Random cookies are getting generated in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, iis, cookies

When I deployed the ASP.NET MVC web application and browse the pages the new random cookies are getting added.
How to know the purpose or source of these cookies or how do I remove these unwanted cookies ?

**Note:** Cookie name changes every time.

Please check the below image.

[image: Check the higlighted cookie names]

Used:
ASP.NET MVC 5, .NET Framework 4.5.2, and IIS 10

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net has by default session state turned on, which in turn relies on cookies by default. If you don't need session state you can turn it off in the web.config file. Just add sessionState mode="off".

```
<configuration>    
  <system.web>       
   <sessionState mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>    
</configuration>
```

Comment: No, I can not do this. Thank you.

Comment: why? do you have any special requirement?

Comment: Yes, I am using Inproc sesssion mode. So can not disable.

Comment: Maybe you can try to recycle the application pool.